# Control image brightness and contrast in an Excel form with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, brightness, contrast

I'm using several instances of the Private Function code below to display multiple images within an Excel form. It works fine. I can use these small html containers to position images in various places on the form.  But I need to be able to adjust the brightness and contrast of the image displayed.

In the past, in a different project, I've displayed images directly on a worksheet, then used the following code to change the brightness (and similarly for contrast). But I'm not figuring out how to do it for this project with images displayed on a form. I could really use some help.

The following is the code used in a different project to increase brightness for all images displayed in the worksheet.  Similar code is used to decrease brightness and increase/decrease contrast.

```
Sub BumpContrastUp()
    gvarGlobalContrast = gvarGlobalContrast + 0.05
    Dim shape As Excel.shape
    Dim cnt As Long
    cnt = 0
    For Each shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If shape.Type = msoLinkedPicture Then
            shape.PictureFormat.Contrast = gvarGlobalContrast
        End If
    Next shape
End Sub
```

The following is the code used to display images on a form.  Several of the HTML containers (at the end) are used to display different images (one image per container) on the form.  Note: I've cut out a bunch of code and tried to leave just what is pertinent for you to see what's going on.  In the end, I need to change the brightness and contrast for picURL1 and picURL2.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With frmImageReview
        .Caption = Sheets("Configuration").Range("B2").Value
        .Height = Sheets("Configuration").Range("B3").Value
        .Width = Sheets("Configuration").Range("B4").Value
    End With
        'BUTTONS ---------------------------------------------------
        With frmImageReview.cmdOK
            .Top = Sheets("Configuration").Range("J21").Value
            .Left = Sheets("Configuration").Range("J22").Value
        End With
        With frmImageReview.cmdBrightPlus
            .Top = Sheets("Configuration").Range("J24").Value
            .Left = Sheets("Configuration").Range("J25").Value
        End With
        With frmImageReview.cmdBrightNeg
            .Top = Sheets("Configuration").Range("K24").Value
            .Left = Sheets("Configuration").Range("K25").Value
        End With
        With frmImageReview.cmdContrastPlus
            .Top = Sheets("Configuration").Range("L24").Value
            .Left = Sheets("Configuration").Range("L25").Value
        End With
        With frmImageReview.cmdContrastNeg
            .Top = Sheets("Configuration").Range("M24").Value
            .Left = Sheets("Configuration").Range("M25").Value
        End With
    'HEIGHT/WIDTH FACTORS (for use in setting height/width in web browsers)
    With Sheets("Configuration")
        HWF1 = .Range("B" & IVProw + 6).Value
        HWF2 = .Range("C" & IVProw + 6).Value
    End With

    With WebBrowser1
        .Height = Sheets("Configuration").Range("B" & IVProw + 1).Value
        .Width = Sheets("Configuration").Range("B" & IVProw + 2).Value
        .Top = Sheets("Configuration").Range("B" & IVProw + 3).Value
        .Left = Sheets("Configuration").Range("B" & IVProw + 4).Value
        .Visible = Sheets("Configuration").Range("B" & IVProw + 5).Value
    End With
    With WebBrowser2
        .Height = Sheets("Configuration").Range("C" & IVProw + 1).Value
        .Width = Sheets("Configuration").Range("C" & IVProw + 2).Value
        .Top = Sheets("Configuration").Range("C" & IVProw + 3).Value
        .Left = Sheets("Configuration").Range("C" & IVProw + 4).Value
        .Visible = Sheets("Configuration").Range("C" & IVProw + 5).Value
    End With
    GetImage
    cmdClearForm_Click
End Sub

Private Sub GetImage()
    With Sheets("Configuration")
        displayPath = Sheets("Configuration").Range("B8") 'Local
        CFIb1 = Sheets("Configuration").Range("B" & IVProw + 8).Value
        CFIb2 = Sheets("Configuration").Range("C" & IVProw + 8).Value
    End With
    picURL1 = displayPath & "\" & Sheets("Image URLs").Range(CFIb1 & r + rDiff)
    picURL2 = displayPath & "\" & Sheets("Image URLs").Range(CFIb2 & r + rDiff)
        fnCreateHTML1 (picURL1)
        fnCreateHTML2 (picURL2)
        Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate strPath & "Tmp1.html"
        Me.WebBrowser2.Navigate strPath & "Tmp2.html"
End Sub


'//-----------------------------------------
'// Author    : "Ivan F Moala"
'// Site      : "http://www.xcelfiles.com"
'-------------------------------------------
Private Function fnCreateHTML1(strImgFilePath As String)
    Dim hdl As Long, m_Width1 As Long, m_Height1 As Long
    Dim strAp1 As String

strAp1 = Chr(34)
m_Width1 = WebBrowser1.Width * HWF1
m_Height1 = WebBrowser1.Height * HWF1
hdl = FreeFile

    Open strPath & "Tmp1.html" For Output As #hdl
        Print #hdl, "<HTML>"
        Print #hdl, "<CENTER>"
        Print #hdl, "<BODY"
        Print #hdl, "Scroll = ""YES"""
        Print #hdl, "LEFTMARGIN=0"
        Print #hdl, "TOPMARGIN=0"
        Print #hdl, "</BODY>"
        Print #hdl, "<IMG width= " & m_Width1 & _
                    " height= " & m_Height1 & _
                    " SRC = " & strAp1 & picURL1 & strAp1 & _
                    "; Border = 0>"
        Print #hdl, "</CENTER>"
        Print #hdl, "</HTML>"
    Close hdl
End Function


Private Function fnCreateHTML2(strImgFilePath As String)
    Dim hd2 As Long, m_Width2 As Long, m_Height2 As Long
    Dim strAp2 As String

strAp2 = Chr(34)
m_Width2 = WebBrowser2.Width * HWF2
m_Height2 = WebBrowser2.Height * HWF2
hd2 = FreeFile

    Open strPath & "Tmp2.html" For Output As #hd2
        Print #hd2, "<HTML>"
        Print #hd2, "<CENTER>"
        Print #hd2, "<BODY"
        Print #hd2, "Scroll = ""YES"""
        Print #hd2, "LEFTMARGIN=0"
        Print #hd2, "TOPMARGIN=0"
        Print #hd2, "</BODY>"
        Print #hd2, "<IMG width= " & m_Width2 & _
                    " height= " & m_Height2 & _
                    " SRC = " & strAp2 & picURL2 & strAp2 & _
                    "; Border = 0>"
        Print #hd2, "</CENTER>"
        Print #hd2, "</HTML>"
    Close hd2
End Function
```

Comment: agh no need to shout

Comment: I wasn't shouting.  I was using caps to distinguish the general description versus verbiage specific to each of the two blocks of code.  I thought it might be helpful to the reader.  But it reads fine in sentence case too.